# forzar una condición palabra exacta en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo esta tabla con un campo llamado `nombre` y `marca_temp`

Los `nombre` de los registros pueden ser:

```
IMPRESORA HP XXXXX
IMPRESORA MP YYYYY
IMPRESORA AMP ZZZZZ
MP IMPRESORA RRRRR
IMPRESORA 3500 MP
IMPRESORA 5200 HP
```

Y tengo este `update` que busca dentro del `nombre` una palabra y la establece en el campo `marca_temp`

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set marca_temp = 'MP' where nombre like '%MP%' and marca_temp = '' ");

tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set marca_temp = 'HP' where nombre like '%HP%' and marca_temp = '' ");

tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set marca_temp = 'AMP' where nombre like '%AMP%' and marca_temp = '' ");
```

Pero tengo un problema, necesito que la palabra en la consulta sea EXACTA ya que por ejemplo todas contienen **MP** por la palabra I**MP**RESORA y me establece en la `marca_temp` todas en **MP**

¿Como hago para que el campo sea la palabra exacta y completa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrías utilizar [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) y marcadores de límite de palabras (`[[:<:]] y [[:>:]]`)

#### Ejemplo:

```
UPDATE $table
  SET marca_temp = '$word'
  WHERE nombre REGEXP '[[:<:]]$word[[:>:]]'
    AND marca_temp = ''
```

*Nota: reemplazar `$table` y `$word`*

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nkpmj7RfaecWRAF6twFm2H/0)</kbd>

---

Aplicado a tu código:

```
$word = 'MP';
$table = TABLE;
tep_db_query("update $table set marca_temp = '$word' where nombre REGEXP '[[:<:]]$word[[:>:]]' and marca_temp = ''");
```

Answer (score 2):

Los *%* dentro de tu clausula `LIKE` a ambos extremos de la palabra a buscar significa que te va a buscar la igualdad independientemente de donde esta se produzca.

Aprovechándote de ello podrías hacer algo como:

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set marca_temp = 'MP' where nombre like '% MP %' and marca_temp = '' ");

tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set marca_temp = 'HP' where nombre like '% HP %' and marca_temp = '' ");

tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set marca_temp = 'AMP' where nombre like '% AMP %' and marca_temp = '' ");
```

Al añadir el espacio delante y detrás de la igualdad deberías conseguir que el `update` solamente se produzca cuando la palabra buscada es la que aparece en el medio de tu campo `nombre`.

Comment: hay un detalle puede ser que este al inicio o al final del campo NOMBRE agrego otro ejemplo arriba ya que no lo considere pero si lo necesito

Comment: Podrías usar `OR` para contemplar esas posibilidades:  `'% MP %'`, `'MP %'`, `'% MP'`.